# insert comments template inside a loop

Tags: php, wordpress

i need to insert the comments template inside the loop of posts. My client don't wanna click on post to comment, he wanna comment os the posts list. How can I do this on wordpress?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WordPress template editor allows you to modify these files through the administration UI.  You simply need to copy the lines of code from the comments template into the post loop.  If you've tried this and are having problems, please update your question with the specific issue.

Answer (score 2):

you should use something like that:

```
<?php
  global $withcomments;
  $withcomments = true;
  comments_template( '', true );
?>
```

inside the loop of posts.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Also it may not help if you have override $post variable in your template.